# Hide nodes from Drupal 7 views based on permissions

Tags: drupal

In a view, I'm going to hide some nodes based on user permissions. I also need to restrict the access to the node on a per-user basis. Nobody except some users that have the permissions should be able to view the node (for example via node/ID).

I thought this is a really simple task but at the moment I can't find a good starting point. I'm anyways in my own module, defined my own content types programatically and now fiddling aroung with the permissions.

I would be thankful for any help or a good starting point. I tried a bit myself but with no real success.

So, thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had also tried the [Node access example](http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/node_access_example!node_access_example.module/group/node_access_example/7) and it seemed not to work but in fact it does. I just tried it as an authenticated user and then the nodes were not hidden from the view listing and I thought the example just doesn't work for views. But as anonymous user, the 'private' flag does its job.
So the [Node access example](http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/node_access_example!node_access_example.module/group/node_access_example/7) seems to be a good starting point and the authenticated/anonymous behavior should be fixable as well.

Comment: Yes, the Node access example was a really good starting point and I could solve my problem. I don't have good explanatory and common code I could share and as everything is very good documented in the Node access example you should take a look in there if you're going to achieve something similar.

Comment: And keep the user permissions in mind during testing. For example the admin will see all nodes, so don't get confused.

Answer (score 1):

With permissions, you want to start at the node level, after all that's where your content originates. I would take a look at the [Content Access](http://drupal.org/project/content_access) Module as well as the [Field Permissions](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) Module. The former sets node level permissions per content type and the latter sets field level permissions per field.

Those permissions are then propagated to Views and you can tweak all you like. It's a little tricky setting all this up but once you do it's pretty good.

There are other [more fine grained permissions modules](http://drupal.org/project/modules?filters=drupal_core:103%20bs_project_sandbox:0&text=permissions) that deal with Taxonomy and other things but what I've listed above is probably a good starting point.

**Screen capture added for Field Permissions**

[image]

Comment: I already tried the Content Access Module but it has no effect on the listing of nodes in views.

Comment: Did you look at the "`Access:Permission`" setting in the View and tweak that according to your needs? Have you tried the Field Permissions Module as well?

Comment: I don't even see any kind of view support for the Field Permissions Module. Am I missing something?

Comment: Doesn't the "Acess: Permission" setting affect the whole view?

Comment: There's also a filter criteria "Content access: Access". I don't know what this exactly does but it seems like this could be helpful... (Afaik this is from no module.)

Comment: I just tested out the **Field Permissions Module** and indeed the fields are available to Views. When you set "Custom Permissions" on the field, that is propagated to the View, it worked for me. (So for example I hid a `slide teaser field` for certain roles and that then worked in the View as well.) I will post a screen capture above.